# Windows service at C# What should I do?

Tags: c#, windows, service

I am writing Windows service at C#. There are OnStart and OnStop function in the Windows service file
The file that is OnStart function " start: the current date " has been written.
The file that is OnStop function " stop: the current date " has been written.
When I restart the computer, it write function into the file. But if I turn off and turn on the computer the functions can't be written in the file. 
What should I do?

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "OnStart.txt", true))
    {
        sw.WriteLine("Açılış:" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "OnStart.txt", true))
    {
        sw.WriteLine("Kapaniş:" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
}
protected override void OnContinue()
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "OnStart.txt", true))
    {
        sw.WriteLine("continue:" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
}
  ___________________________________________________
```

Kapaniş:16.03.2016 01:01:04
Açılış:16.03.2016 01:02:08

Comment: Show some code. And explain what you mean by for instance _The file that is OnStop function " stop: the current date " has been written._ This sentence makes no sense.

Comment: You should provide more info - I suggest including code for OnStart and OnStop, also include where you are trying to write these messages, how you configured the service to run, whether it actually starts automatically, and whether there are any errors in the Event Log when it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you saying your service writes to a file on start and stop, but when you stop the computer and start again, the service does not start up?

Comment: It works when Windows restarts . When not writing, but when closed when the file restarts .